# Wait for asynchronous logging to finish before Thread ends slf4j/log4j2

Tags: asynchronous, logging, log4j2, slf4j

I'm using an asynchronous database logging setup with slf4j/log4j2. All is working as expected.

The only drawback is, that sometimes when the server is shut down the logger has not completed writing to the database (e.g. if there was a burst before shutdown).

I get:

> WARN AsyncLoggerConfigDisruptor: shutdown timed out after 0
>   MILLISECONDS Log4j2-TF-1-AsyncLoggerConfig-1 ERROR Attempted to append
>   to non-started appender databaseAppender

And I lose everything that was in the logger-buffer.

Is there a way in `slf4j` or `log4j2` to wait for the asynchronous logger to finish (e.g. a blocking call at the end of a task)?

Or at least to get the size of the buffer, that still needs to be written?

Currently, I use a setup with synchronous file logger and an asynchronous database logger, so the data is still in the file...

--> Edit 02/28/19

Here is a quick and dirty example code:

```
protected static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(App.class);

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Runnable task = new TestLogging(i);            
        executor.submit(task);
    }
    executor.shutdown();
    System.out.println("Done");
    //LogManager.shutdown();
}

private static class TestLogging implements Runnable {

    private int i;

    public TestLogging(int i) {
        this.i=i;
    }

    public void run() {
        // Generate a big string for DB test
        StringBuffer b=new StringBuffer();
        IntStream.range(0, 1000).parallel().forEach(i -> b.append(UUID.randomUUID().toString()));
        // Writing to context for logging
        MDC.put("test", "test"+i);
        MDC.put("test1", b.toString());
        // Log 1000 lines 
        IntStream.range(0, 1000).forEach(j -> logger.error("Exception " + j + "-"+ i, new RuntimeException()));
    }
}
```

The configuration xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <File name="MyFile" fileName="all.log" immediateFlush="false"
            append="false">
            <PatternLayout
                pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} tx.id=%X{test} tx.content=%X{test1} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </File>
        <JDBC name="databaseAppender" tableName="log_test">
            <PoolingDriver connectionString="jdbc:oracle:thin:@centos.fritz.box:1521:orcl" userName="test"  password="test"  driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
         <Column name="LOG_ID" pattern="%u" />
         <Column name="ENTRY_DATE" isEventTimestamp="true" />
         <Column name="LOGGER" pattern="%logger" />
         <Column name="LOG_LEVEL" pattern="%level" />
         <Column name="MESSAGE" pattern="%m" />
         <Column name="EXCEPTION" pattern="%throwable" />
         <Column name="ID" pattern="%X{test}" />
         <Column name="XML" pattern="%X{test1}" />
        </JDBC>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <AsyncRoot level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="databaseAppender" />
        </AsyncRoot>
        <Logger name="com.test" level="trace" includeLocation="true">
            <AppenderRef ref="MyFile" />
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

And for Oracle the DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE "TEST"."LOG_TEST" 
   (    "LOG_ID" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "ENTRY_DATE" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "LOGGER" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "LOG_LEVEL" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "MESSAGE" CLOB, 
    "EXCEPTION" CLOB, 
    "ID" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "XML" CLOB, 
     PRIMARY KEY ("LOG_ID"))
```

If I use the 
`LogManager.shutdown();`

The logging doesn't even start. Without, depending on the DB, I get about 500-1000 lines in the DB, before the error appears.

The logging in the real database will be much more sparse, this is just a worst-case test... and as mentioned, the logging in the file works. It would just be nice, to have a consistent logging in DB and file, even if the service is shut down.

Comment: Good question, but adding a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would make it even better.

Comment: @Jens Popp were you able to find some approach towards it ?

Comment: Unfortunately no. We just let both outputs run in parallel with a log rotate. In case of error the log files are saved before restart